# Do we need a mythology/folklore tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I'm looking at this new question 
[What are the components of a legend (in the sense of a tale, not a figure legend)?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/45130/what-are-the-components-of-a-legend-in-the-sense-of-a-tale-not-a-figure-legend)
and went to add a [mythology](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythology) tag, but we don't have one!

We also don't have [folklore](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/folklore) or [legends](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legends)

As the question I linked to points out, creating such background for your world is often an important task.  This question is on topic because it's asking how to write the legends.  But other questions about mythology and the like are also on topic for Writing.  An author can use myths for research, inspiration, or character development.  Or an author may wish to duplicate or echo the structure of a myth.  In addition to the story in the above question, many authors write folktakes and such either for their world or just outright.  It's a genre, and not one you can just toss into [fantasy](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy)

I would consider [mythology](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythology), [folklore](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/folklore), and [legends](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legends) to refer to the same thing.

There are [26 questions with the keyword "mythology"](https://writing.stackexchange.com/search?q=mythology%20is%3Aq) plus another 14 (non-dups) [with the keyword myth](https://writing.stackexchange.com/search?q=myth%20-mythology%20is%3Aq).  Only [2 questions with "folklore."](https://writing.stackexchange.com/search?q=folklore%20is%3Aq)  And [1 question with "folk"](https://writing.stackexchange.com/search?q=folklore%20is%3Aq) that does not also have "mythology" and is about folk tales.  [1 question about folktales](https://writing.stackexchange.com/search?q=folktale%20is%3Aq). [22 questions about legends](https://writing.stackexchange.com/search?q=legend%20is%3Aq).

I have not checked all these for duplicates or suitability for such a tag, but it looks like there are a fair number.

My suggestion is that I start a tag that encompasses all these things.  The primary name can be either mythology or folklore or folktale or legend, but we might want to consider synonyms too.  The reality is that you can not search the text of tags, only the names (and the synonyms don't come up under tags, only if you're adding to a question).

Note: that this is a related Meta discussion, though not a duplicate. [Do we need an 'ethnicity-religion-race' tag?](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1896/do-we-need-an-ethnicity-religion-race-tag)

Please let me know what you think.

Comment: I've gone ahead and created [tag:mythology] and will slowly retag (as not to flood).

Answer (score 1):

## Mythology should exist without synonyms

From your research I think these questions need better tagging. Those 26 questions should definitely have the [mythology](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythology) tag. It is relevant are useful.

However I disagree that [mythology](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythology) and [folklore](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/folklore) are the same thing. Source from [this article](https://aliisaacstoryteller.com/2016/09/26/mythology-and-folklore-whats-the-difference/) the Oxford English dictionary defines mythology as:

> A collection of myths, especially one belonging to a particular religious or cultural tradition. A set of stories or beliefs about a particular person, institution, or situation, especially when exaggerated or fictitious.

While folklore is described as:

> The traditional beliefs, customs, and stories of a community, passed through the generations by word of mouth. A body of popular myths or beliefs relating to a particular place, activity, or group of people.

I think there is enough distinction between these two things to warrant *not* being synonyms or falling under a single tag. Though they share a lot of similarities I don't think they should be the same.

Interestingly though with only those few questions it is difficult to make a case for [folklore](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/folklore) to exist and perhaps a better tag would be [legends](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legends) as it seems more popular.

I suggest you go ahead and make the [mythology](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythology) tag but we shouldn't rush to make synonyms. Folklore may emerge as its own tag at some point and breaking the synonym will be more difficult then.

Comment: Well both definitions you cite use the term "myths" and the term "beliefs."  While it's true that mythology has a pejorative use as well, we're not using it in that sense.  So I still maintain that mythology and folklore overlap enough to combine.  But I'd like to hear what others think.  Thanks for answering though.  This question has gotten very little attention, but then again it's sort of a holiday weekend.

Comment: @Cyn I can certainly see the arguement for it. If usage indicates they should be synonyms I wouldn't argue however I don't think we need to pre-emptively synonymise them when they are both new tags. I'm not sure what to do with the legends questions though.

Comment: I'm inclined to tag it mythology and also the others and put the keywords folklore, folktale, and legend into the wiki.  And let new tags or synonyms come about if needed in the future.

Comment: @Cyn That seems like a reasonable compromise to me. I'm happy for the [tag:mythology] to cover them all, without being explicit synonyms. If we need another tag down the line we can make one then.

Comment: Okay, [tag:mythology] exists.